# Using regex to access values from a map in keys

Tags: regex, scala

```
val m = Map("a"->2,"ab"->3,"c"->4)

scala> m.get("a");


scala> println(res.get)
2

scala> m.get(/a\.*/)
// or something similar.
```

Can i get a list of all key-value pairs where key contains "a" without having to iterate over the entire map , by doing something as simple as specifying a regex in the key value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot do that without iterating over the entire map. In fact, I can't even think of a single data structure that would allow it, say nothing of the API.

Of course, iterating is pretty simple:

```
m.filterKeys(_ matches "a.*")
```

Comment: I think `m.filterKeys(_ contains "a" )` is better solution.

Comment: @SergeyLagutin But that wouldn't be regex, and, in fact, would return results that are not "start with a", which was the example.

Comment: I don't see requirement that key should "start with a".

Comment: @SergeyLagutin `/a\*/` -- assuming he missed a period before the star, since, otherwise, this regex would match all strings.